# Is it possible to generate custom email report for azure metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

My Aim is this:
My company has 5 webapps and some other resources running on Microsoft Azure. An e-mail is to be sent daily that would contain

- CPU and memory utilization of the 5 webapps
- DTU percentage of SQL DB
- Observed capacity of Autoscale

Currently this is done manually by taking screenshots of the metrics. Could this be automated via API or something else? I looked into application insights API, but couldn't find the info for SQL databases and auto-scale metrics.
If someone could just lean me on the right path, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Azure Monitor REST API".

> All metrics: Contains DTU/CPU percentage, DTU/CPU limit, physical data
>   read percentage, log write percentage, Successful/Failed/Blocked by
>   firewall connections, sessions percentage, workers percentage,
>   storage, storage percentage, and XTP storage percentage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-metrics-diag-logging

and also the Azure Monitor REST API reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/

Then simply you can use a logic app to send the email every day.